# Relating two sets of JSON data in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm loading two sets of data separately but I'd like them to be related. Allow me to explain.

Firstly, I'm not using Ember-data but am instead using a simple `$.ajax` wrapper as outlined in [this post from one of the Discourse team](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html).

I have a concept of channels and programmes.

**Channels JSON:**

```
[{
  "ID":94,
  "Name":"BBC1"
},
{
  "ID":105,
  "Name":"BBC2"
}]
```

I have to gather the IDs from this JSON to be able to then request the programmes for those channels. So a response from the programmes endpoint will look a bit like this:

**Programmes JSON:**

```
{
    "Channels": [
        {
            "Listings": [
                {
                    "Id": "wcy2g",
                    "Genres": "Education",
                    "S": "2013-04-26T10:45",
                    "E": "2013-04-26T11:15",
                    "T": "Crime Scene Rescue"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Listings": [
                {
                    "Id": "wcwbs",
                    "Genres": "Current affairs,News",
                    "S": "2013-04-26T11:00",
                    "E": "2013-04-26T12:00",
                    "PID": "nyg",
                    "T": "Daily Politics"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Each `Listings` array can contain x amount of programmes and the objects in the `Channels` array relate to the order in which they are requested (by the IDs from the Channels.json) so in this case `Channels[0]` is BBC1 and `Channels[1]` is BBC2.

What I'd like is to request these two data sets as a single JSON request each but then somehow relate them. So having a channel controller that has x amount of programme models. I also need to render the channels and their programmes in two different templates

Was thinking I could iterate through the `channels.json` and use the index of the item to look up the relevant items in `programmes.json` and create the relationship that way.

Not too sure how to use Ember to achieve this though.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something very similar to this and got it working in ember.  I'll sketch out what I did, using your objects.  Note that I'm fairly new to ember so a grain of salt may be necessary.

First, you'll want to have model objects for "Channels", "Channel" and "Programme".  This will eventually let you have Controllers and Routers for each of those things, matching up nicely with ember's naming conventions.  The ChannelsData will have many ChannelData objects in it, and each ChannelData will have many ProgrammeData objects.  How do you get these populated?

In your ChannelsRoute class you can have a model() function which returns the model data for that route.  Your model function can call create() on ChannelsData to create an instance, and then call a loadAll function on ChannelsData.  ChannelsData implements loadAll() using your preferred flavor of ajax.  The dead-simple easiest thing to do is to have that function do both of your ajax calls and build the entire tree of data.

You will then find that you'll run into trouble if your ChannelRoute class tries to call its model(), for instance if you enter a path like #/channels/105 directly into the browser.  To work around that, make a simple object store of your own on your App object, something like App.ChannelsStore = {}, and when you create each Channel put a reference to it in your ChannelsStore (by id).  Then your ChannelRoute.model function can look up its model from that store.  But only if ChannelsRoute.model has completed first!

If the user entered that #/channels/105 route as the very first entry into your app, then your code will go through the ChannelsRoute.model() method, and immediately go through the ChannelRoute.model() method, probably before your ajax has completed.  In that case you can have the ChannelRoute.model() method create a temporary Channel (with no programmes, for instance) and put that in the App.ChannelsStore.  Your logic for building up the whole tree of data should then be willing to check the ChannelsStore to see if an object with a given id already exists, and if so to update it.  You end up with something like:

```
App.ChannelRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var channel = App.ChannelsStore[params.channel_id];
    // create stub version if not found
    if (!channel) {
      channel = App.ChannelData.create({ID: params.channel_id});
      App.ChannelsStore[params.channel_id] = channel;
    }
    return channel;
  }
});
```

(You may end up building a ProgrammeStore similarly, but that's just more of the same.)

The updating of the temporary object actually demonstrates a very cool aspect of ember, which is that your ui may be presented with the values from the temporary object, but then when your ajax call completes and the Channels and Programmes are all loaded - your ui will update properly.  Just make sure you update your objects with the set() method, and that your ui templates are happy to work with partial data.

Comment: This is great stuff, thank you. Regarding your points on the storing and routes, this will all be happening off one Route (it's an interactive grid). So I'll likely hook everything up in the setupController method. How would you approach creating the programme models and relating them to each channel once both sets of JSON are fetched?

Comment: Some version of an `each` method will take care of you.  For instance, jQuery's each would allow you to run through your programmes json, giving the index and value of each element of the channels array.  That will then get you what you need to connect to your channels json.